# apex chart donut items border raduis

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am looking to make my donut chart items corners round please guide

[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQavY.png)

[what I have made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xurs9.png)

```
const Chart = dynamic(() => import('react-apexcharts'), { ssr: false });
```

```
 const series = [54, 45];
  const options: ApexCharts.ApexOptions = {
    chart: {
      width: 380,
      type: 'donut',
    },
    labels: ['Active Users', 'Inactive Users'],
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        expandOnClick:false, 
        donut: {
          size:'85%',
          labels: {
            show: true,
            name: {
              show: true,
              fontSize: '12px',
              fontWeight: '400',
              color: '#6E7191'
            },
            value: {
              show: true,
              fontSize: '22px',
              fontWeight: '600',
              color: '#2E285C'
            },
            total: {
              show: true,
              color: '#BCC1C8',
              fontWeight: 600,
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 480,
      options: {
        chart: {
          width: 200
        },
        legend: {
          show: false
        }
      }
    }],
    legend: {
      position: 'left',
      offsetY: 50,
    },
    colors: ['#645CAA', '#BFACE0'],
    title: {
      text: '264',
      align: 'left',
      floating: false,
      style: {
        fontSize: '36px',
        fontWeight: '500',
        color: '#2E285C'
      },
    }
  }
```

```
<Chart series={series} options={options} type="donut" />
```

That I have been tried but I cannot find any solution to change border radius of this chart. I have searched on google but could not find it That I am writing because stackoverflow saying its too much code write Details(alflsjdfakfjlkasdhkf jdfjkhdfkjd kdjfjkdhfkjhd jfsdjhfkdh kdfhsdkfj jdfksjhdfkj ksdjfkdjhf jkjkdhfkdsf jhdfkhsfjk jsdhjfkhdk jfhsdkjf jfksjdh fjdksjhf djfkh kjdsjkf jfhskdf )

Comment: I would prefer chartjs for this purpose, as there already exmples like this one and great community support also.

Comment: @junaidShaikh brother I have to do this in apexchart

Comment: sorry but it is not achievable, look what maker of apexcharts said `https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/910#issuecomment-529864711`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry that I couldn't find any official solutions for border-radius in Donut chart, however, you may try **RadialBar** or **Circular Gauge chart** as an alternative.

There, Apexchart provides you a [`lineCap` option](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/stroke#lineCap) (in `stroke`), which allows 3 values `butt`, `square` & `round`. I also tried the `lineCap: round` for Donut chart but unfortunately, it didn't worked.

And, so, if you really need the border of the donut, you can create an issue in their [GitHub](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues).